# Error de consulta Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy probando Hibernate a ver si esta todo correcto configurado y eso. Al ir a robar la consulta:

```
SELECT  * FROM City as c
```

Me da este error

```
rg.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 9 [SELECT  * FROM City as c]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
```

Esta es la clase city que tiene su xml

```
public class City  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Short cityId;
     private Country country;
     private String city;
     private Date lastUpdate;

    public City() {
    }

    public City(Country country, String city, Date lastUpdate) {
       this.country = country;
       this.city = city;
       this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }

    public Short getCityId() {
        return this.cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(Short cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }
    public Country getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdate() {
        return this.lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(Date lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
}
```

El hibernate until

```
mport org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

el hibernate reverg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="sakila"/>
  <table-filter match-name="country"/>
  <table-filter match-name="city"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

y la configuracion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="Hibernate/City.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="Hibernate/Country.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Este es el xml de city

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15-ene-2020 17:55:32 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Hibernate.City" table="city" catalog="sakila" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="cityId" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="city_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="country" class="Hibernate.Country" fetch="select">
            <column name="country_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="city" type="string">
            <column name="city" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_update" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa la sintáxis de HQL (Hibernate Query Language) en vez de SQL:

`SELECT c FROM City as c`

o también puedes omitir el select y usar:

`from City as c`

Consúlta los ejemplos de HQL en la documentación de Hibernate para la versión que estás usando.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html

**Update**: Verifica que el paquete y el mapeo usen la misma ruta, por ejemplo:

en City.java:

`package com.unknown;`

y en el xml de City:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.unknown.City" table="city"
```

La estructura del folder `src` debe seguir, de preferencia, la misma estructura de los paquetes:

`.../src/com/unknown/City.java`

Comment: si uso from city as c  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: City is not mapped [from City as c]

Comment: Mapéa City: que hay en `Hibernate/City.hbm.xml`?

Comment: Te edito la pregunta para ponerlo

Comment: @unknow Parece que falta el 'package statement' hasta arriba de la clase City. la ruta debe ser la misma en el package y en el mapeo:

Answer (score 0):

también
 puede ser "from City" solamente, no es necesario usar alias, ya que no usaras la tabla para hacer otras operaciones.

por otra parte como lo estas haciendo también esta bien, solo que tienes que indicarle a Hibernate que estas usando unas query nativa (createNativeQuery).

saludos.